# Unable to repopulate form

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have created the below mentioned form in Codeigniter, where there is 4 level dependent drop down list. Everything work as expected while I am in the first form. When I press the add button so that there is a regenerated form just like the first one, whenever I select the country field and expect based on my selection to have the relevant options in the second drop down menu (championship) it doesn't work. No data is coming based on my country selection. It looks like there is no call to the JavaScript.
Could you please help me to understand where is my mistake after pressing the add button, so that no matter how many forms I create, I will have relevant calls to the functions in my controller where it brings the relevant data to the depentened drop down menus?
Thank you very much!

```html
 <div class="container box">
  <br />
  <br />
  <h3 align="center">Available Championships</h3>
  <br />
  <?php echo form_open_multipart('dynamic_dependent'); ?>
  <div id="dynamic_field">
  <div class="form-group">
   <select name="country[]" id="country" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <?php
    foreach($country as $row)
    {
     echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
   </select>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="form-group">
   <select name="championship[]" id="championship" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select Championship</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="form-group">
   <select name="home_team[]" id="home_team" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select Home Team</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <select name="away_team[]" id="away_team" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select Away Team</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="prediction[]" id="prediction">
  </div>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?> 
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){      
      var i=1;  
   
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;             
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<div id="row'+i+'"><div class="form-group"><select name="country[]" id="country" class="form-control input-lg"><option value="">Select Country</option><?php foreach($country as $row) { echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>'; } ?></select></div><div class="form-group"><select name="championship[]" id="championship" class="form-control input-lg"><option value="">Select Championship</option></select></div><div class="form-group"><select name="home_team[]" id="home_team" class="form-control input-lg"><option value="">Select Home Team</option></select></div><div class="form-group"><select name="away_team[]" id="away_team" class="form-control input-lg"><option value="">Select Away Team</option></select></div><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="prediction[]" id="prediction"></div><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></div></div></div>');
     });
     
     $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
           var res = confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Delete This?');
           if(res==true){
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
           $('#'+button_id+'').remove();  
           }
      });  
  
    });  


$('#country').change(function(){
  var country_id = $('#country').val();
  if(country_id != '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/dynamic_dependent/fetch_state",
    method:"POST",
    data:{country_id:country_id},
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#championship').html(data);
     $('#home_team').html('<option value="">Select Home Team</option>');
     $('#away_team').html('<option value="">Select Away Team</option>');
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#championship').html('<option value="">Select Championship</option>');
   $('#home_team').html('<option value="">Select Home Team</option>');
   $('#away_team').html('<option value="">Select Away Team</option>');
  }
 });

 $('#championship').change(function(){
  var championship_id = $('#championship').val();
  if(championship_id != '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/dynamic_dependent/fetch_city",
    method:"POST",
    data:{championship_id:championship_id},
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#home_team').html(data);
     $('#away_team').html(data);
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#home_team').html('<option value="">Select Home Team</option>');
   $('#away_team').html('<option value="">Select Away Team</option>');
  }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Any advise please? I am totally stuck and and cannot proceed further without it...

Comment: Do you want to generate a new form when the button is clicked, like this? https://www.sanwebcorner.com/2017/02/dynamically-generate-form-fields-using.html

Comment: Thank you @heathscliff for your comment, regarding the form, it works, i managed to repopulate it with the above mentioned code but after pressing the add more button, the issue is that to the next repopulated forms the calls to the functions / controllers don't work. Only the first select box which has the query direct inside it, works. The others don't..

Comment: Okay, no prob. Now the point is not all form inserted to the database, right? Can you show the function / controller code?

Comment: Dear @heathscliff, the problem is not related to the controller since it never reach the controller ...., it is that in the new generated form after selecting the add button, the new drop down menus never call (through ajax) the controller when selecting something (on change). I added some console logs inside the code and i see that it never goes inside the JavaScript function ($('#country').change(function(){)  and i cannot understand why...